# Git Ignore for metadata and other settings?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, git, github

[image: Git Ignore and git status]

I'm having a problem with my .gitignore, since it seems to be ignoring the file extensions in there. Every time I change any file I end up with hundreds of other files. I've looked at previous posts on here to deal with the problem, and I copied what I have in my .gitignore from a git repository: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore 
but that doesn't seem to be working. I've restarted Eclipse, refreshed my git repo and nothing is happening.

Any advice?

Comment: It's hard to tell from a cluttered screenshot, but I'm guessing you put the `.gitignore` into a subdirectory of your project, going by the `../` prefixes on the PATHs. I'm guessing `.gitignore` only applies to the directory it's in and its subdirectories, not the project as a whole. You should move the `.gitignore` to the root of your Git repo.

Comment: Are you using the git plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Egit. 
I've tried moving the .gitignore so hopefully that'll do the trick.

Comment: I moved the .gitignore up a directory, so it's in the same location as  .git (not in that folder), which just caused the error of there being no .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

It seems those files have been added to the git repository already.

Are those "not staged files" or "untracked files"? In case of former, you remove files from repository using following commend.

```
git rm --cached
```

Comment: I've used git add -A to add everything to a commit, but it doesn't seem to be adding it to the index. Also when I use your command it's just giving me a list of options to use with the rm command; it's not actually doing anything. After a commit there's still untracked files.